# set date range in ggplot

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

my data frame is z:

```
library(ggplot2); library(scales)
z <-     structure(list(Month = structure(c(14975, 15095, 15156, 15187, 
15248), class = "Date"), Value = c(1, 1, 1, 6, 1)), .Names = c("Month", 
"Value"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")


ggplot(z, aes(Month, Value)) + 
    geom_bar(fill="orange",size=.3,  stat="identity", position="identity") +
    geom_smooth(data=z,aes(Month,Value,group=1), method="lm", size=2, color="navyblue") + 
    scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", labels=date_format("%b-%Y"))
```

This works ok but I really like my data range between 1/1/2011 and 1/1/2013. My example date is from 1/12011 to 10/1/2011. Is there an easy way to force the date range from 1/1/2011 to 1/1/2013 in ggplot?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The documentation at `?scale_x_date` mentions that it accepts all "typical" continuous scale arguments, including `limits`:

```
library(scales)
ggplot(z, aes(Month, Value)) + 
    geom_bar(fill="orange",size=.3,  stat="identity", position="identity") + 
    geom_smooth(data=z,aes(Month,Value,group=1), method="lm", size=2, color="navyblue") + 
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", 
                 labels=date_format("%b-%Y"),
                 limits = as.Date(c('2011-01-01','2013-01-01')))
```

Comment: Useful answer, but lack of `library(scales)` call generated `Error in structure(list(call = match.call(), aesthetics = aesthetics,  : 
  could not find function "date_format"`, which had me scratching my head for a couple of minutes!

Comment: @SlowLearner Sorry, the OP's code wouldn't run either without `library(scales)`; it wasn't the `limits` bit that requires it.

Comment: This code does not work for me. Maybe the big update to ggplot2 broke it. `Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`.

Comment: @Deleet I can't reproduce that error. I was getting an error due to an outdated argument name (`breaks` vs `date_breaks`) but it was a different error. The code works fine for me now.

Comment: I found that the solution was to use: `scale_x_datetime(limits = c(d_brexit$Date[which.min(d_brexit$Date)], dmy("23 Jun 2016")))`. I.e., use scale_datetime. Cryptic error message makes it difficult to debug. Here's the context: https://gist.github.com/Deleetdk/880b4b0653361d0b5e6b4c911f5ae2bb

Comment: @Deleet Your comment hints at issues that may have been causing you problems that have nothing to do with the code in this question or in my answer (which all work fine, now). You appear to be using lubridate functions, which may return objects that do inherit from class Date. Which might explain your error message.

Comment: @Deleet Yes, looking at your gist, the error message was not cryptic at all. Your Date column was not actually a Date column. It was POSIXct. And `date_trans` dutifully informed you that it worked only on columns of class `Date`.

Answer (score 13):

It would be a courtesy to SO users to note that you have in addition to 'ggplot2' also loaded the `scales` package. There is an `ggplot2::xlim` function, so this works:

```
  ...... + xlim(as.Date(c('1/1/2011', '1/1/2013'), format="%d/%m/%Y") )
```

Update: Just got a downvote for an unexplained reason. The code in the original question no longer works, but if you replace the scale_x_date(.) call with just the xlim() call above there is no error.

```
ggplot(z, aes(Month, Value)) + 
     geom_bar(fill="orange",size=.3,  stat="identity", position="identity") +
     geom_smooth(data=z,aes(Month,Value,group=1), method="lm", size=2, color="navyblue") + 
     xlim(as.Date(c('1/1/2011', '1/1/2013'), format="%d/%m/%Y") )
```

[image]

Comment: This code does not work for me. Maybe the big update to ggplot2 broke it. `Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`.

Comment: The code still works in 3.4.1 so the comment from last year makes no sense. I was clearly give a Date-classed value to `xlim`. Probably failure to recognize a factor variable that looked like a "Date" in the printed output.

Comment: This technically works for me, but if I put it after `scale_x_date()` it breaks whatever settings I gave to `scale_x_date()`. If I put it before, `scale_x_date()` breaks the settings I put in `xlim()`. Using ggplot version 3.3.2.

Comment: @GMSL I think asking a question about a seven year-old answer that has already been modified once to keep track of package modifications is expecting too much from the SO comment mechanism. You should write up a new question.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using ggplot 3.1 which requires the least tweaks to the original code:

```
ggplot(z, aes(Month, Value)) + 
    geom_bar(fill="orange",size=.3, stat="identity", position="identity") +
    geom_smooth(data=z,aes(Month,Value,group=1), method="lm", size=2, color="navyblue") + 
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", 
           limits = as.Date(c('1/1/2011', '1/1/2013'), format="%d/%m/%Y"),
           date_labels="%b-%Y" ) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

the `theme()` at the end is optional, but makes the formatting easier to read if you want to use your original `"%b-%Y"` formatting string.