# Setting the x-axis min and max in using ggplot when ploting over POSIXct time

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, plot, posixct

I am trying to plot values over time and am getting the error:

```
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

I worked through earlier problems with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736819/error-with-scale-x-labels-in-ggplot2) as well as [the post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162829/set-date-range-in-ggplot).  I want to set the min and max of the x- axis to remove the blanks space on the extreme ends of plot where there is no data.

This code calls a plot, but without the corrected x- axis.

```
ggplot(dta, aes(x= WeekStarting, y = AvgWeekEle, group = IndID))+
        geom_line(size = 1)+ 
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=30, hjust=1))
```

I tried to set the limits of the x-axis using `scale_x_date` with the code below - which produces the error.

```
ggplot(dta, aes(x= WeekStarting, y = AvgWeekEle, group = IndID))+
        geom_line(size = 1)+ 
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=30, hjust=1))+
        scale_x_date(breaks = "1 week", labels=date_format("%b-%d-%Y"), 
            limits = as.Date(c("2014-01-6","2014-02-15")))
```

A `dput()` of my data are below.  I am using the newest version of R and am running Windows 7.

Thanks in advance.

```
dta <- structure(list(IndID = c("BHS_011_A", "BHS_011_A", "BHS_011_A", 
"BHS_011_A", "BHS_011_A", "BHS_011_A", "BHS_011_A", "BHS_011_A", 
"BHS_015_A", "BHS_015_A", "BHS_015_A", "BHS_015_A", "BHS_015_A", 
"BHS_015_A", "BHS_015_A", "BHS_015_A", "BHS_018_A", "BHS_018_A", 
"BHS_018_A", "BHS_018_A", "BHS_018_A", "BHS_018_A", "BHS_018_A", 
"BHS_018_A"), WeekStarting = structure(c(1388905200, 1389510000, 
1390114800, 1390719600, 1391324400, 1391929200, 1392534000, 1393138800, 
1388905200, 1389510000, 1390114800, 1390719600, 1391324400, 1391929200, 
1392534000, 1393138800, 1388905200, 1389510000, 1390114800, 1390719600, 
1391324400, 1391929200, 1392534000, 1393138800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), AvgWeekEle = c(1717.21428571429, 1770.07142857143, 
1737.53571428571, 1673.32142857143, 1648.42857142857, 1760.71428571429, 
1668.48148148148, 1654.5, 1643.5, 1794.85714285714, 1740.64285714286, 
1664.73076923077, 1704.73076923077, 1685.2962962963, 1707.89285714286, 
1661.46428571429, 1702.87096774194, 1691.17647058824, 1653.41176470588, 
1650.30303030303, 1741.54545454545, 1652.33333333333, 1573.125, 
1570.82352941176)), .Names = c("IndID", "WeekStarting", "AvgWeekEle"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(3362L, 3363L, 3364L, 3365L, 
3366L, 3367L, 3368L, 3369L, 3470L, 3471L, 3472L, 3473L, 3474L, 
3475L, 3476L, 3477L, 3535L, 3536L, 3537L, 3538L, 3539L, 3540L, 
3541L, 3542L))
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that suggestion in the linked posts. But following your suggestion I get the error 'Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only' As both suggestions resulted in an error, I figured I would start at the beginning.  Any thoughts on the 2nd error following your suggestion?

Comment: Changing to `scale_x_datetime` works for me. Note you also need to change the `limits=` from `as.Date` to `limits = as.POSIXct`

Comment: Embarrassing and humbling...  thanks!  Would gladly accept an answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your x variable is of class `as.POSIXct` you should use `scale_x_datetime` instead. `scale_x_date` is for variables of class `Date` (as the error message may suggest).

"To remove the blanks space on the extreme ends of plot", you may use the `expand` argument in your `scale` call (see [**here**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/continuous_scale.html)). Setting `expand` to zero, removes the default, small gap between data and axes.

You may also have a look at [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots/3606798#3606798) to use the `limits` argument in the `scale` call (or `xlim`), or use `coord_cartesian` to 'zoom'.

```
ggplot(dta, aes(x= WeekStarting, y = AvgWeekEle, group = IndID)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = "1 week", labels = date_format("%b-%d-%Y"),
                   expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image]