# adjust line graph in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISF2u.png)

How do you adjust the line graph to avoid so much spare space?.
Is scale alpha the way to trim the line graph?.

```
ggplot(cdata) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Value)) +
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [set date range in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162829/set-date-range-in-ggplot)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scale_x_*` and `scale_y_*` family of functions in ggplot2 to control the scaling and limits of the axes.

Assuming your `cdata$Date` is a Date, you can do the following:

```r
ggplot(cdata) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Value)) +
  scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-12-31")))
```

EDIT: If you are looking to scale the y axis, it is continuous, so you could use `scale_y_continuous()`. There are also other scaling functions available, like `scale_*_discrete()`, `scale_*_log10()`, and `scale_*_reverse()`, depending on the type of values on your axes.

Comment: and then for the y axis, you do something like scale_x_value(limit = as.Dbl(c("2e.00,))?

Comment: The y axis appears to be continuous, so you could use `scale_y_continuous()`.

Comment: so I tried scale_y_continous(limits = c(1e.05, 3e.00)) but it came up with an empty graph

Comment: You misspelled 'continuous' and have periods (.) instead of plus signs (+). Try: `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1e+05, 3e+00))`